# Formula to verify row values and retrieve columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table in Excel as shown in the attached image (Until Column F) and would like to see the final column "Result":

ExcelData:
[image: ExcelData]

The Result column should retrieve Column Names where the row values is "IF".

I can use the IF function in Excel, but that would be a long statement that I would have to write to retrieve the final output if there are like 20 columns that I would have to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Excel Online you can try the texjoin

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(B2:G2="IF",$B$1:$G$1,""))
```

Comment: Hi @usmanhaq, I am getting an error when trying to use the textjoin function.

Comment: it is an array formula, are you pressing Ctrl+Shift+Enter, and a side not that array formulae are not available on free version of Excel online.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESQa1.png - I am using normal excel, but still getting an error. Hope this image helps. Not sure if I'm doing anything wrong.

Comment: double click in the cell and press Ctrl+Shift+Enter

Answer (score 1):

If you are okay with creating a UDF (User Defined Function), then you can essentially create your own worksheet function to do this.

In this function, you will do a quick loop in the input range, and check if any cell in that range is equal to "IF". If so, you will strip the column letter out of the `.Address` property.

```vb
Public Function getIFCols(ByVal rng As Range) As String

    Dim retVal As String, cel As Range

    For Each cel In rng.Cells
        If cel.Value = "IF" Then
            retVal = Trim(retVal & " " & colLtr(cel))
        End If
    Next

    getIFCols = Replace(retVal, " ", ", ")

End Function

Private Function colLtr(colRng As Range) As String

    colLtr = Split(colRng.Address, "$")(1)

End Function
```

You will call this function as such:

```
=getIFCols(B1:F1)
```

> [image]

The great thing about this function is that it doesn't require a set amount of columns. So if you need 3 columns checked on one row and 10 on another, it's pretty dynamic.

Comment: Thanks Davis. It's helpful. If I am using online excel it looks like it doesn't support writing user defined functions. Is there an alternate way as well?

Comment: Yeah Excel online I believe will stop VBA code from running - So in this case I would recommend that you unaccept this answer since you are still needing assistance -- If it helps, you can still upvote if you'd like but I wouldn't accept it.